# Google Maps Listener in Backbone.js View

Tags: backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to toggle open and close Infowindow divs on markers on my google map in a Backbone.ja app.

In my view I have an initialize function that has google.maps.event.addListener.

```
function initialize(viewOptions, app) {
  this.app = app;
  this.address = '';
  this.terms = [
      'Food',
      'Bar'
    ];
  // this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addmarker);
  this.render();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    console.log('Clicked')
    // infoclicker.call(); 
  });
};
```

This addListener does not seem to work. When I click a marker, or even just anywhere on the map it does not trigger console.log. What am I doing wrong here?

Also FYI: there is a _setMap function called by the render function, that sets the map.

```
function _setMap(zoom, lat, long) {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: zoom ? zoom : 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat ? lat : 45.5200,long ? long : -122.6819)
    };

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
};
```

Comment: What is `map` in that `addListener` call?

Comment: I believe 'map' is instance of the google map object created in the _setMap function.

Comment: Is there a `#map-canvas` when you call `_setMap`?

Comment: There is a #map-canvas in the map template when _setmap is called.

Comment: Just in the template or on the page itself? Have you checked that `document.getElementById('map-canvas')` is returning what you expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
});
```

Comment: This looks like it. In addListener you are referencing to `map` variable which does not exist. You are storing it as object attribute in `this.map`. In case `_setMap` is method of the same object as `initialize`

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of the variables you are using for the map and marker. They should be in scope of the function in which you are trying to add the action listener on them.